# How to count how many distinct urls there are using pandas

Tags: pandas

[image]

How can I separate and count how many distinctive com.XXXXX.XXX . Or how would I make this into a readable data frame with all the possible com.XXXXX.XXX as the headers and if there are no entry then represent it as 0

right now the txt is in this format
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that that I understand you. You want to first separate urls in the form `com.XXXX.XXX` from others and then count how many distinct ones you have ? A one-liner should be enough, something like this, assuming the name of the urls column is `urls`:

```
len(trainN_df[trainN_df["url"].str.contains("^com\.")].replace("^com\.","",regex=True).drop_duplicates())
```